# can google map send push notification to user without app install?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, notifications, location

I need some help to understand better about google maps push notifications.

Nowadays we are getting push notifications from different restaurants, hotels or shops whenever we visited or leave the area.
how this is happening. Do we need to use any product from the Google to support this feature or Google is promoting the app itself?

I need the same feature to integrating for my project. so whenever a person comes to a place within the radius defined. we need to track their location using GPS and google maps. and once the person leaves the area we need to send a push notification to their mobiles

But our goals is to a person should not **install any other Android or IOS app and bluetooth is off**. The notification should be get using the Google maps only

so can anyone please let me if this can be achieved? do we have any APIS which Google can provide

Answer (score 0):

Your phone should be subscribed for the Push Notifications. So some app in your phone did this. Also it is impossible to be subscribed without user's permission (at least at iOS). You can check permissions in app settings.

to get more undestanding you can look into: [Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)